# How do I add different users data on my Django backend?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a bunch of users on my django backend. Let's say each user has a field 'age'. I would like to add every users age and divide by the number of users to get an average. Would this best be done in a ModelView as a function that makes a call using a While loop (while User.age for example)?

Comment: What do you mean with add ? Build a sum ?

Comment: Yes sum the Integer fields

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **aggregation**:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
User.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('age'))

Output: {'age': 34.35}
```

So you do not need to build a sum on your own. Django handles it for you.

Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) when you want to do other operations like getting the oldest human.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Avg** from django aggregate in your view function.

```
from django.db.models import Avg

avg_age = User.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('age'))
```